# simple.data how to exec oracle package?

Tags: oracle11g, package, simple.data

simple.data how to exec oracle package??
OracleParameter p1=new OracleParameter("mycs",OracleType.Cursor);
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_members
    AS
        TYPE myrctype IS REF CURSOR;

```
    PROCEDURE get (p_id NUMBER, p_rc OUT myrctype);
END pkg_members;
```

.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_members

AS
    PROCEDURE get (p_id NUMBER, p_rc OUT myrctype)
    IS
       sqlstr   VARCHAR2 (500);
    BEGIN
       IF p_id = 0 THEN
          OPEN p_rc FOR
             SELECT *
               FROM members;
       ELSE
          sqlstr :=
             'select *
            from members where id=:p_id';
          OPEN p_rc FOR sqlstr USING p_id;
       END IF;
    END get;
END pkg_members;
```

****And when I do that:
DbContext.Open().pkg_members__get(12);
error below:
Simple.Data.Ado.AdoAdapterException : ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'get'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored****

Comment: Please show all the complete client code calling this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.Data does not know about Oracle packages (nor do I, for that matter). It sounds like something that is very database specific and therefore beyond the reach of a cross-platform data access library.